# Matplotlib/Tkinter bug: exception when comparing collection3d objects

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm getting a strange exception raised by a Matplotlib window's Tkinter callback. Context: I'm running Python 3.2 in a QTconsole IPython window, in pylab mode. The problem I'm coding involves 3D plotting over triangular regions.

(I apologize if the code snippet is rather long; I found the bug difficult to reproduce.)

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
A,B,C,D = array([[0,0],[1,0],[1/2,1],[3/2,1]])
f1 = lambda x,y: NaN if x==y==0 else (y - 2*x)*sin(1/(x**2+y**2))
f2 = lambda x,y: NaN if x==y==0 else (y-2*x+2)*cos(1/(x**2+y**2))
(U,V) = meshgrid(linspace(0,1),linspace(0,1))

fig = figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection = '3d')

(X1,Y1) = vectorize(lambda u,v: tuple(A + u*(B-A) + u*v*(C-B)), otypes = [float,float])(U,V)
(X2,Y2) = vectorize(lambda u,v: tuple(D + u*(C-D) + u*v*(B-C)), otypes = [float,float])(U,V)
Z11 = vectorize(f1)(X1,Y1)
Z21 = vectorize(f2)(X1,Y1)
Z12 = vectorize(f1)(X2,Y2)
Z22 = vectorize(f2)(X2,Y2)

ax.plot_wireframe(X1,Y1,Z11)
ax.plot_wireframe(X1,Y1,Z21)
ax.plot_wireframe(X2,Y2,Z12)
ax.plot_wireframe(X2,Y2,Z22)
show()
```

Once all these patches are drawn, a mouse-click in the figure window produces the following:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1399, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
[snip]
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line 191, in draw
    zlist.sort()
TypeError: unorderable types: Line3DCollection() < Line3DCollection()
Exception in Tkinter callback
```

Since this is a Tkinter-raised exception, I can't catch it in PDB and analyze it. (In particular, there are a lot of unnamed arguments passed to the intermediate methods in the stack trace that make it impossible to follow it down by hand.) I have been able to figure out that, indeed, the Axes3D instance is trying to sort its list of Line3DCollection objects and running up against an un-implemented comparison method.

My question is: is this a bug that Matplotlib needs to be made aware of, or am I making some kind of basic user mistake? (As mentioned, the bug is finicky; it doesn't always show up, especially if I parametrize the triangles in different ways.)

Comment: What version of mpl are you using?  I don't get this on an install close to the current master (but I might have gotten lucky).  I think this is worth creating a MPL issue over if updating doesn't make it go away.  The exception is coming from way down in the backend and the the 3D code has had a lot of work recently.

Comment: I would create an issue for this.  There is a 1.2.x release candidate out that you might want to try.

Comment: I just read this again, I missed the bit about QTconsole the first time.  That makes me confused by why you are even calling tkinter.  You should include the mpl version and which backend you are using in the github issue.

Comment: I'm confused; I'm not calling Tkinter by hand at all, it's just the backend for MPL, which is running in a normal IPython session. If I were calling it by hand, I could catch the exception and trace it myself.

In any case, the exception is raised somewhere in the execution of a Tkinter callback; but it's raised by a command in a MPL method, so it's not a TK problem per se.

Comment: I (apparently incorrectly) assumed that using qtconsole -> you are using the QT backend for matplotlib.

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: MPL rolled out 1.2.1 last week, and after I installed the upgrade the problem didn't appear. I didn't do any serious testing, however.

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept it (when it will let you).  Knowing the problem exists, and maybe fixed by upgrading is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed by updating mpl 1.2.1 (as reported in comments to OP).