# Matplotlib: contourf3d_demo2 example doesn't work with python3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-3.3

The current docs for the matplotlib mplot3d contourf function contain two examples:

[mplot3d tutorial - Matplotlib 1.2.1 documentation](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#filled-contour-plots)

One of them, contourf3d_demo2.py works with python v2.7.3, but fails with the following error when I use python v3.3.1:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: Poly3DCollection() < Poly3DCollection()
```

The other example, contourf3d_demo.py, works fine. Is there anyone else using matplotlib with python v3.3 who could confirm this?

Comment: existing issue: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1831

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441695/matplotlib-tkinter-bug-exception-when-comparing-collection3d-objects

Comment: What version of mpl are you using?  This may be fixed in 1.2.1.

Comment: 1.2.0 is being used with both python 3.3.1 and python 2.7.3 . I determined this by calling __version__ as imported from matplotlib.

Comment: try updating to 1.2.1, the other SO question about this reports that fixes it.